# Decision rule for most powerful test with two exponential variables

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential random variables with $E(X_1)=\theta$ and $E(X_2)=2\theta$. Find a most powerful test of $H_0: \theta=2$ versus $H_\alpha: \theta=4$. Give the decision rule for $\alpha = 0.05$

$E[X_1]=\frac{1}{\lambda_1}=\theta$ $\rightarrow$ $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{\theta}$

$E[X_2]=\frac{1}{\lambda_2}=2\theta$ $\rightarrow$ $\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2\theta}$

$\frac{L(\theta_0;x_1,x_2)}{L(\theta_\alpha;x_1,x_2)}= \frac{\frac{1}{8} e^{\frac{-x_1}{2}}e^{\frac{-x_2}{4}}}{\frac{1}{32} e^{\frac{-x_1}{4}}e^{\frac{-x_2}{8}}}$

$\frac{L(\theta_0;x_1,x_2)}{L(\theta_\alpha;x_1,x_2)}= 4e^{-\frac{2x_1+x_2}{8}}$

$2X_1+X_2$ is a sufficient statistic

How do I relate this quantity to the $\alpha = 0.05$ to find the decision rule?

Answer (score 1):

You should reject the null when $2X_1 + X_2$ is large. (Why?)

That is reject when $2X_1 + X_2$ exceeds some threshold $T$ determined by the size of the test.

$2X_1 + X_2 \sim_{H_0} \Gamma(2,4)$, and so just find a $T$ such that $\mathbb{P}( \Gamma(2,4) > T) = 0.05$. This gives a UMP test of size $0.05$. (Why?)

Comment: It is the sum of two exponentials so you get a gamma with n=2. Why does Beta = 4?

Comment: I use the shape and scale parameterisation of a Gamma variable. $2X_1$ and $X_2$ are both independent$ \Gamma(1,4) $variables, so their sum is $\Gamma(2,4)$.

Comment: When under the null hypothesis, $2E[X_1] = 2\theta = 4$ so $2X_1 \sim \Gamma(1,4)$ and $X_2 \sim \Gamma(1,4) \because E[X_2] = 2 \theta = 4$

Comment: Reject when $2X_1+X_2 \geq$ qgamma(.95,2,rate=1/4)

Comment: Yes that's equivalent.